# Cannot understand part of the lecture on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot understand how projecting vector $b$ onto vector $a$ gives us a side $e$ of a right triangle which we can express as $e = b - p$?
Video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_Ac6KiQ1t0)

[image]

Comment: You know how to find the vector sum graphically?

Comment: Following ΘΣΦGenSan's comment, it's not too difficult to visually see that $p+e=b$. Subtracting $p$ from both sides gives the desired result.